# Facebook feed post not seen by public - ios sdk

Tags: objective-c, facebook

I'm using the facebook ios sdk 3.1. In ios 6 the integration has no issues since it uses the native dialog. In ios 5.1, I implemented a fallback to use the feed dialog. The post shows up in user's timeline but doesn't appear in friend's newsfeed. I've tweaked the setting of the facebook app to 'public' but problem still exist.

```
- (void) publishUsingFeedDialog {
    if (_facebook == nil) {
        _facebook = [[Facebook alloc]
                     initWithAppId:FBSession.activeSession.appID
                     andDelegate:nil];
        // Store the Facebook session information
        _facebook.accessToken = FBSession.activeSession.accessToken;
        _facebook.expirationDate = FBSession.activeSession.expirationDate;
    }

    // @"Facebook SDK for iOS", @"name",
    // @"Build great social apps and get more installs.", @"caption",
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"My test with app", @"name",
                               [self getDescription], @"description",
                               @"http://www.test.com", @"link",
                               @"http://www.test.com/logo.gif", @"picture",
                               nil];

    // Invoke the dialog
    [_facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:(id)self];
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I didn't include any caption information: @"my caption", @"caption". Even though I can still post without any problems, but facebook algorithm will sometimes hide it from public.